# Counting no. of characters between headers in python

Tags: python

I have the following dataset, my code below will identify each line with the word 'Query_' search for an '*' and print the letters under it until the next line with 'Query_'

```
Query_10      206  IVVTGPHKFNRCPLKKLAQSFTMPTSTFVDI*GLNFDITEQHFVKEKP**SSEEAQFFAK  385
010718494     193  LLVTGPLVVNRVPLRRAHQKFVIATSTKVDISGVKIHLTDAYFKKKKLRKPKQEGEIFDT  255
001291831     173  LLVTGPLSLNRVPLRRTHQKFVIATSTKIDISSVKIHLTDAYFKKKKP--RHQEGEIFDT  235
012359817     173  LLVTGPLVLNRVPLRRTHQKFVIATSTKIDISNVKIHLTDAYFKKKKP--RHQEGEIFDT  235
009246541     173  LLVTGPLVLNRVPLRRTHQKFVIATSTKIDISNVKIHLTDAYFKKKKP--RHQEGEIFDT  235
Query_13      31    MEEQKEKGLSNPEVV*KYRQCSEIVNQVLSTVVSSCVPGADVASICTNGDFLIEDGLRNI  210
002947167     7     IQGEQEPNLSVPEVVTKYKAAADICNRALQAVIDGCKDGSKIVDLCRTGDNFITKECGNI  66
004993505     1     MELDRQSKVVDADALSKYRAAAAIANDCVQQLVANCIAGADVYTLAVEADTYIEQKLKEL  60
006961234     1     MSETKEYSLNNPDTLTKYKTAAQISEKVLAAVSDLCVPGAKIVDICQQGDKLIEEELAKV  62
008089018     1     MSEETDYTLNNPDTLTKYKTAAQISEKVLAAVAELVVPGEKIVTICEKGDKLIEEELAKV  60
Query_13      211   EPDTNIEKGIAIPVCLNINNICSYYSPLPDASTTLQEGDLVKVDLGAHFDGYIVSAASSI  390
```

I am looking to print only if there are at least 50 or more letters under the '*' between the Query_ lines. Any help would be great!

```
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open('infile.txt')]
for line in lines:
    data = line.split()
    sequence = data[2]
    if data[0].startswith("Query_"):
        star_indicies = [i for i,c in enumerate(sequence) if c == '*']
    else:
        print(list(sequence[star_index] for star_index in star_indicies))
```

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into steps

First find all the lines with headers, and mark whether they contain asterisks:

```
headers = [[i,"*" in l.split()[2]] for i,l in enumerate(lines) 
           if l.startswith("Query_")]
```

So now you have a list of lists, each containing two values

- Index into `lines` of the header
- Whether that header contains an asterisk

Now you can iterate over it

```
for i, header in enumerate(headers[:-1]): # All but last
    if not header[1]:
        continue // No asterisk
    this_header = header[0]
    next_header = headers[i+1][0]
    if (next_header - this_header -1) < 50:
        continue // Not enough rows
    ...
```

The `...` above is where you put the code to figure out which columns of `lines[this_header]` contain asterisks and then extract those columns from `lines[this_header+1]` through `lines[next_header-1]`.

I've left that bit for you as your question is underspecified

- Does the file end with a "Query_" header line?
- If not, how do you deal with the case where the final header line has asterisks and is followed by 100 more lines?
- What do you mean by "print the letters under it"?

But this should get you started